# Generic compareTo class

Tags: java

I want to make somehow generic type class, with method named leiaSuurem. Objective is to compare two integer, which one is bigger. If, for example, x is bigger than y, then x is max.

```
public class Vordleja  {
    public int leiaSuurem <T extends Comparable<T>> T
    maksimum(T x, T y){
        T max = x;
        if(y.compareTo(max) > 0) max = y;
        if(x.compareTo(y) > 0) max = x;
        return max;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Largest ( 3, 4 ) element is : " + maksimum(3, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You need to make the leiaSuurem method static

Answer (score 3):

That's not a valid method signature. You have what looks like two method names (`leiaSuurem` and `maksimum`), and two return types (`int` and `T`). The correct signature should be `public <T extends Comparable<T>> T maksimum(T x, T y)`.

Also your main method must be static, and therefore `maksimum` must also be changed to static to be called from within main:

```
public class Vordleja  {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maksimum(T x, T y){
        T max = x;
        if(y.compareTo(max) > 0) max = y;
        if(x.compareTo(y) > 0) max = x;
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Largest ( 3, 4 ) element is : " + maksimum(3, 4));
    }
}
```